# Selenium makes "Browser under control" and test fails

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jenkins

Yesterday, we changed the encoding preferences to UTF-8 from Eclipse, because it was a problem to execute from Jenkins, and now, since then, I have another problem...

When I run my tests from Eclipse, Selenium Webdriver open new Window and go to a web page. Now, it opens the web page, and minimize and show "The browser is under remote control" and so, in consequence, it makes my tests fail, because the webelement changes the position (before, the web page is maximized).

I've tried doing "maximize" or send "F11" keys like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\.....\\geckodriver-v0.17.0\\geckodriver.exe");
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("usertest");
    testprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    testprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
    testprofile.setPreference("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", false);
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, testprofile);
    dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("http://webpage.com/");

    //fullscreen 
    try {
        // press F11 key of keyboard to switch the browser to full screen
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception (ignored) " + e.toString());
    }
```

And it doesn't work.

I show you the image:

[image: Browser under remote control]

I have to say that before this, I executed all my tests correctly, without that message "Browser under remote control" and without minimizing window...

Why has it changed? Why show "remote control" if my computer isn't being controlled??

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing below line from your code.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed version 54.0.1 of Firefox and it fixed, the problem was with the update.